# Match up everything before STRING or STRING

Tags: c#, regex, string, matching

I've searched for hours and already tried tons of different patterns - there's a simple thing I wan't to achive with **regex**, but somehow it just won't do as I want:

### Possible Strings

#### String1

> This is some text \0"§%lfsdrlsrblabla\0\0\0}dfglpdfgl

#### String2

> This is some text

#### String3

> This is some text \0

#### Desired Match/Result

> This is some text

I simply want to match **everything** - **until** and **except** the `\0` - resulting in only 1 Match. (everything before the `\0`) 
**Important** for my case is, that it will match everytime, even when the `\0` is not given.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Do you mean the string backslash-zero or are you representing a null character?

Comment: Sorry, I meant a "backslash-zero" - (is it even possible to declare a null character in regex?)

Comment: @user2615607: yes with `\u0000`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with this pattern:

```
@"^(?:[^\\]+|\\(?!0))+"
```

In other words: *all characters except backslashes or backslashes not followed by 0*

Comment: Wow, fast response - and hell, I get headache alone from looking at this, but it works like a charm - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I like

```
@"^((?!\\0).)*"
```

Because it's very easy to implement with any arbitrary string.  The basic trick is the *negative lookahead*, which asserts that the string starting at this point doesn't match the
regular expression inside.  We follow this with a wildcard to mean "Literally any character not at the start of my string.  If your string should change, this is an easy update - just

```
@"^((?!--STRING--).)*)"
```

As long as you properly escape that string.  Heck, with this pattern, you're merely a `regex_escape` function from generating any delimiter string.

Bonus: using * instead of + will return a blank string as a valid match when your string starts with your delimiter.